# Does the JavaScript method array.forEach work in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[Here's my demo.](http://jsbin.com/ekivuf/2/edit#javascript,html,live)

I'm trying to get the JavaScript `forEach` method to work in Google Chrome. 

[Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=foreach) hasn't been much help. :(

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason not to use jQuery? performance?

Comment: @EranMedan My case is small, my pageload is fast, and I'd like to keep it that way. :)

Answer (score 14):

Convert the NodeList to an array:

```
nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes);
```

Then you can use `.forEach()` on it.

Comment: Does not work in browsers where host objects can't be used as *this* for native methods. Which is moot because those browsers probably don't support qSA anyway...

Comment: Are you sure this is a problem in any browser? jQuery does exactly this.

Comment: **Any** user agent where you can't treat host objects as native objects (and there really is no reason to think you can in the first place), IE 8 and lower being an example. jQuery doesn't use that method on host objects, only on native arrays. Note that the majority of IE users are still on IE 8 or lower.

Comment: Hrm indeed. However, this would mean underscore is broken, too: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-31 - and I think if it was really broken in IE8 people would have noticed.

Answer (score 2):

`document.querySelectorAll` doesn't return array but a `NodeList` object which has no method 'forEach'.

The error msg shows you that:

```
Object #<NodeList> has no method 'forEach'
```

Check [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList), which explains this.

Comment: Yeah I saw that. What does it mean? What would be an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Just convert it using some modern JavaScript:

```
let paragraphs = Array.from(nodes)
paragraphs.forEach(paragraph => console.log(`This is the paragraph: ${paragraph}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call `forEach` but on arrays.

In your case, the data may not be in an array, it may be an `HTMLCollection` and that's why you are seeing this error, you can fix this by changing the data to `Array`, like this:-

```
// HTMLCollection
const allJobs = document.getElementsByClassName('component_4d072');

// Array
const arrayAllJobs = [...allJobs];

// and now you can run
arrayAllJobs.forEach(jobs => console.log(jobs));
```